# versionCode of Android Application and In-app Purcases

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

I have 2 ways of distribution of app:

1. Google Play
2. Email

In both cases I have in-app purchases.  Will a user be able to purchase in-app using email version of app if `versionCode` is larger in Google Play (after update)?

Comment: Sure. Users are not forced to update their app from the Play Store either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No that's not possible. I faced the problem a week ago... The versionCode of the app must coincide with the one of Google Play otherwise you get an error like "This app is not prepared for Google Play... please refer to the documentation..."